# How to support smaller screens on android, even after using support screens?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I need my app to work on screens of all sizes. It works perfectly on my SII, but the complete app is not showing on the galaxy Y. I am using the support screen code in manifest. I can't find whats wrong.

Here's the code in manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true" 
              android:largeScreens="true"

              android:anyDensity="true"
              />
```

Comment: Did you checked the Android Version of galaxy Y? Since you have given android:minSdkVersion="8" if your device version is lesser it will not appear

Comment: Yes. It was 2.3, which is 10, so i think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring screen sizes is not all that is needed. You also need to provide layouts and drawables for each screen size. See [How to Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support).

Answer (score 0):

I have *never* needed to use the `<supports-screens>` tag.  Just leave it out, and you automatically support every screen size.

Comment: Here is the link of the application, still not working proprerly on galaxy y                            https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kshitij.bmi

Comment: Interesting.  It shows as compatible with every device I have except the G1 (which is excluded because it is API level 4).

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you have a bunch of images in drawable-hdpi and nowhere else (Galaxy Y is ldpi).  Maybe you can put those into drawable or drawable-nodpi instead.  EDIT: You should be okay, per http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html.  I just can't think of anything else.